# Cannot access this when ng-keyup is called the second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, keyup

There is an input field like:

```
<input ng-if="$ctrl.inputType === 'input'" 
    name={{$ctrl.param.Name}}
    type="text"
    ng-keyup="$ctrl.keyp()"
    ..."
/>
```

and the keyp() function in controller:

```
class AlertParameterCtrl {
    constructor(AlertParameterService, $element){
        this.AlertParameterService = AlertParameterService;
        this.$element = $element;
        this.overrideText = 'Override default';
        this.inputType = 'input';
        this.unitlessParameter = false;
    }
 ...
    keyp() {
        const dec = 2;
        const regex = new RegExp("(\\.\\d{" + dec + "})\\d+", "g");
        this.param.value = this.param.value.replace(regex, '$1');      
    }

}

AlertParameterCtrl.$inject = ['AlertParameterService', '$element'];
```

The aim is to make possible to introduce maximum of 2 digits after the decimal point.

I had put a `debbuger` inside `keyp()` to see how it is behaving. When there is added a new digit after the decimal, the value of `this.param.value` remains on step before.

For example, if the inital value is `100` and I write `100.`, the value of `this.param.value` remains `100`.

After this step, I introduce another digit, `100.2`, the value of `this.param.value` becomes `100.` and so on.

So, when there are 3 digits in the input and 2 digits in the variable (`this.param.value`), I'm writing another one to see if it will stop it from putting it in the input form.

But instead of using the regex for doing so, the value of `this.param.value` is undefined and I'm receiving this error:

> Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

---

Does anybody know why are these 2 problems occur? Like being on step before and why when the 3rd digit is introduced the variable storing it is undefined?

Comment: can you show your controller? I believe you use the wrong scope for a controller, which is referred with `this`. You might need `var vm = this;` and use `vm.param.value` instead

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I updated the code with the controller